# Slick carousel breaking my sites responsiveness

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

Im running slick carousel
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

**It seems to work fine apart from these 2 points:**

*The left arrow breaks out of my site

*The carousel isn't staying responsive like the rest of my page. Resulting in having to scroll horizontally. Running carousel by itself works great but once incorporated into my site it does this.

*I cant plug my sites and slicks code here so you will have to work off the raw page.*

My code wont fit within the limit of the post and i have no way of getting the plugin in to work off codepen

Slick is completely unmodified and the only settings ive activated are those at the bottom of the page in the js.

www.techagesite.com/slick integrated.htm

Comment: In production i don't. :)

Comment: Thanks for that. That would make problem 3 as it works locally. Fixed

Comment: Should point out that the page needs to be viewed at a smaller resolution with something like ff web dev responsive design view

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Its because the left button is being offset to the left without the added margin to the container to fit it in.

Change your CSS file to look like this

```
.responsive {
  height: 150px;
  width: 93%;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Now all thats left if the non responsiveness of the slider